# Unable to display form fields and objects in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create multiple forms in one template page(dischargedetails.html)  using different views. Each form model is having foreignkey Ipd,First form (ProcedureForm) is working fine but the in Second form(investigation Form) not able to display investigation date feild and investigation name field

models.py :

```py
class Investigation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    ipd = models.ForeignKey(Ipd,on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    report = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)

class Procedure(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    ipd = models.ForeignKey(Ipd,on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    report = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    time = models.TimeField( blank=True,default=now)
```

urls.py :

```py
re_path(r'^(?P<ipd_id>\d+)/dischargedetails/$', my_patient.discharge_detail, name='discharge_details'),
```

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def discharge_detail(request,ipd_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ipd,pk=ipd_id)

    if request.method =="POST": 
        procedure = ProcedureForm(request.POST)
        if procedure.is_valid():
            procedure.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        else :
            return HttpResponse(procedure.errors.as_data())
    else :
        prolist=Procedure.objects.all().filter(ipd=ipd_id)
        procedure = ProcedureForm()
        return render(request, 'dischargedetails.html',{'object':object,'procedure':procedure,'prolist':prolist})

    if request.method=="POST":
        investigation = InvestigationForm(request.POST)
        if investigation.is_valid():
            inves = investigation.save(commit = False)
            inves.object = object
            inves.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(investigation.errors.as_data())
    else :
        investigationlist = Investigation.objects.all().filter(ipd=ipd_id)
        investigation = InvestigationForm()
        return render(request, 'dischargedetails.html',{'object':object,'investi':investigation,'investilist':investigationlist})



@login_required
def create_investigation(request,ipd_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ipd,pk=ipd_id)
```

template

```html
<form  method="post" action="{% url 'discharge_detail' ipd_id=object.ipd_id  %}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Date</label>
<div class="input-group date">
{{ investi.date| add_class:'form-control' }}
<label id="addNotesIDhelp" class="error" for=""></label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<textarea id="notesTextId" name = "report" type="text" placeholder="Add Investigation"class="form-control" value = "{{investi.report}}" required></textarea>

<div class="form-group">{{investi.name | add_class:'form-control'}} <label>Report Name</label></div>

</div>



                                   {% for pro in investilist %}
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <div class="shadow w-100 p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                                                <div class="media-body" style="background-color: rgb(173, 181, 212)">
                                                  <h4 class="media-heading">{{pro.name}}{{pro.date}}</h4>
                                                  <br>
                                                  <p style="color: black">{{pro.report}}</p>
                                                   <br>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                              </div>
                                              {% endfor  %}
```

Comment: Displaying "one template page using different views" is simply not a thing you can do. Only one view is called at a a time.

Comment: To add some detail: when you request a URL, your Django url dispatcher will match it with **one** view. That view is responsible for rendering your page, if you want two forms in it, instantiate both forms in your **one** view.

Comment: i have instantiate both form in one view, but still not working can you please tell me where i am going wrong, i have updated my code

Comment: read your code, code execution can never reach the second `if request.method == POST` because you always return before it. You should combine the logics, not just paste the code of one view after the other. It's just python.